# Capturing mousemove for a single layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

How would I listen to mousemove events in OpenLayers 4 that only relate to a single layer, not the whole map?

I have an `ol.layer.Image` layer with the `ol.source.ImageCanvas` source. There is a zoom control ("+" and "-" buttons), and attribution ("i" button) on top. I need to only handle events related to the image layer, such as clicks/mouse movements/touch events/..., but ignore events for the other layers, like the zoom control.

Comment: Layer is on the map, it's not a solely exist. You may need to add listner for map and then check mouseposition where it's on the specific area.

Comment: @ChaseChoi I don't know the location of the zoom control buttons - I basically need to capture all events that is not handled by the controls like zoom +/- buttons.

Comment: I don't actually get your meaning. could you explain with basic OL example? http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/accessible.html

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you unintentionally misused the word *[layer](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.html)*, which has a specific meaning when talking about OpenLayers. *Layers* are graphical map data, while Zoom and Attribution are *controls*.

To listen for mousemove event, add a listener. Here is an example that changes the mouse pointer to a hand when hovering over any feature:

```
map.on('pointermove', (evt) => {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    // the event is a drag gesture, this is handled by openlayers (map move)
    return;
  }
  const pixel = this.map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    pixel,
    someFeature => someFeature // returns first element,
    {
        // optional, filter the layers forEachFeatureAtPixel looks at
        layerFilter: function(layer) { return true; }
    }
  );
  this.map.getTarget().style.cursor = feature ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```